# A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

Tags: c#, proxy, reverse

I'm coding an application which can make a reverse proxy connection but I have a problem!
The error is here: `new Form1.ProxyConfig()`

When I try to run it I get an error: "**A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable**"

```
private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.startToolStripMenuItem.Text == "Start")
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();

        if (form2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        int num1 = Form1.ProxyListenerStart(ref new Form1.ProxyConfig()
        {
            pclient_port = form2.ClientPort,
            pp_start = form2.LocalStartPort,
            pp_end = form2.LocalEndPort
        }, ref this._PN);

        if (num1 != 0)
            int num2 = (int) MessageBox.Show("Error " + num1.ToString());
        else startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Stop";
    }
    else
    {
        Form1.ProxyListenerStop();

        startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Start";
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "0";
    }
}
private struct ProxyConfig
{
    public int pclient_port;
    public int pp_start;
    public int pp_end;
}
```

Comment: This is a very strong indication that the method shouldn't be passing the parameter by reference in the first place, because the caller isn't expecting the variable to be mutated (because there is no variable).

Comment: @Servy No, it's not an indication of that at all. If the caller doesn't have a ref parameter then you would get a very different type of error message. This is a completely different issue: expressions can't be assigned to ... as the error message very explicitly says.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm not saying that the caller should just omit the `ref` keyword and then it will work, I'm saying that the fix is to change the method *so that it no longer passes the parameter by reference*, rather than changing it to pass in a variable rather than a value.  It's not just about fixing the compiler error, but actually writing a good solution.

Comment: My statement above is correct: the error is not a very strong indication that the parameter should not be passed by reference -- the two issues are completely orthogonal. The caller may need to update the ProxyConfig passed to it -- there's no way to know that from the above code. And it's likely that the OP didn't write and has no control over ProxyListenerStart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot create a variable and pass it as a reference at the same time like you're doing there. Try this:

```
var config = new Form1.ProxyConfig()
{
    pclient_port = form2.ClientPort,
    pp_start = form2.LocalStartPort,
    pp_end = form2.LocalEndPort
};

int num1 = Form1.ProxyListenerStart( ref config, ref this._PN );
```

The reason is that it really wouldn't make any sense, consider the following scenario:

```
if( int.TryParse( "123", out new int() ) )
{
    // there's no way for us to actually use the value TryParse stored
    // into the out parameter, since it doesn't have a name
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a 32/64 bit mismatch to me. Are you loading some non .net dll?

Comment: Thanks For The Correction, Now Another Error Appear **"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"**

Comment: Yes I do That it's **proxlib.dll**

Comment: 32 bit dll? Is your project set to "Any CPU" and are you on a 64-bit OS? If so, try forcing it to be 32 bit.

Comment: This is true it's 32bit DLL file and i use 64bit, I'll try that thanks ♥

Comment: As a side note, you should think a bit about the comment Servy left. It does seem odd to have that parameter as a ref.

Comment: I've Another Problem I Think It's The Last!
this.Invoke((Delegate) new Form1.NTFCBNewProxy(this.NewProxy), (object) addr_ip, (object) addr_port, (object) local_port);

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Something is null somewhere, step through it in the debugger and have a look. But you really should just search for that message here, you'll find heaps of information about it.

Comment: This is All What I Got:
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at PROXYNOVA.Form1.NewProxy(String addr_ip, Int32 addr_port, Int32 local_port) in c:\Users\cazanova\Desktop\PROXYNOVA\PROXYNOVA000\Form1.cs:line 168
  InnerException:

Comment: Interestingly, I get this error in the following case, too:
`
`const int dataLength = 16*1024;
byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
XferData(ref data, ref dataLength);`
Here, if the `const` is removed, all is fine. Why is this so? `XferData` is not changing the length of the array.

Comment: @Chris Servy's comment is completely wrong. If ProxyListenerStart didn't have a ref parameter then the compiler would just say so, instead of the completely different message it did produce: "A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable". And there's nothing odd about ProxyListenerStart taking a ref parameter; it's obviously going to set some fields in the ProxyConfig passed to it.

Comment: @davidanderle You get an error because you can't modify a const, so it makes no sense to pass it to a ref parameter. The compiler doesn't know or care whether XferData actually changes its parameter or not (and it can't know even if it wanted to, due to the halting problem).

Comment: @CazanovaHaxor Visual Studio will tell you exactly where that exception occurred and what variable was null.